# Proof $\frac{1}{2}\cdot(x^{\alpha}+y^{\alpha})\gt(\frac{x+y}{2})^\alpha$ $(x,y>0,x\neq y,\alpha>1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Proof $\frac{1}{2}\cdot(x^{\alpha}+y^{\alpha})\gt(\frac{x+y}{2})^\alpha$ $(x,y>0,x\neq y,\alpha>1)$

Using Jensen's inequality we have.

$\frac{1}{2}\cdot(x^{\alpha}+y^{\alpha})\geq (\frac{x+y}{2})^\alpha$

$1$).How get strict inequality.

$2$)Can you help geometrically imagine this?

Comment: You have strict inequality because $t \mapsto t^\alpha$ is *strictly* convex.

Comment: Ok thanks this part is clear only remain second question.